# How do keyboards handle simultaneous inputs?

Tags: keyboard, input, input-device

Lately I have been working with the basics concepts of concurrency in programming. One of the thoughts that came across my mind was simultaneous inputs from keyboards. In programming, a method or function is called through an event listener that passes only a single key press at a time. A programmer has to program the code in a certain way to handle simultaneous/multiple key presses. I am wondering how hardware processes a "truly simultaneous" input. Is there some sort of mechanism that automatically prioritizes perceived inputs in a certain order?

Comment: Nothing is truly simultaneous. Time stamps can have millisecond accuracy ...

Comment: so it is completely impossible to achieve the "simultaneous input" on purpose or by pure chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your specific question about keyboard inputs.  The computer receives keystrokes along a serial link, therefore the keystrokes are not received simultaneously as they must be - *er* - serial.

WIthin the keyboard itself is a small processor that reads keypresses and sends them out to the computer on the serial link.  Let us consider the case where someone mananges to press two keys 'simultaneously' (whatever that actually means in terms of temporal precision).  The keyboard processor is scanning a matrix of digital inputs which give it the keypresses.  It will always see one press before another, simply because of its scan across the keys.  Even in this scan takes microseconds, one press will be detected before the other.

It is indeed possible that, due to this scanning, the presses may be very close together but the second is seen first.

In the more general field of real-time process controls, it is likely that an interrupt mechanism is employed whereby inputs interrupt a processor to inform it of an event.  Again, even if the events cannot be separated in time, one interrupt will get to the processor before the other.

Decently written event-driven software must allow for the fact that two events may be detected very close together and could actually be seen in reverse sequence.

Other sequencing gotchas can be found in cases of I/O processors reporting to a controller computer with a protocol that effectively aggregates inputs.

In summary, can truly simultaneous input be achieved - No.

Comment: I suspected that that keyboards used an 'array' and one 'input' would always register first, but now I know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Each pressing or releasing of the key will be transfered from the keyboard to the computer through the USB cable, so there is no way for the keyboard to send true simultaneous key operations. The keyboard just send messages when a key is pressed or released. The computer will tell the application that two keys are pressed if one "key pressed" message arrives before the "key released" message for the last pressed key.

Comment: good point it only gets a 0 or a 1. I wonder if quantum electronics could achieve concurrency...